# Wordpress get attachment image caption

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to get attachment meta caption value as [mentioned here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata), but couldn`t get any output. Other meta arrays like [created_timestamp] or [iso] gave their values.

```
$img_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
echo $img_meta[image_meta][caption];
```

This issue happens to both [caption] and [title]. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could be the value is just empty or that the value doesn't exist at all. Anyway try "[print_r($img_meta)](http://php.net/print_r)" this should display the entire array with keys and values.

Comment: That is the image meta from the picture not from WordPress - so it looks like your images don't have that meta data applied when they were taken. The same as the example on the codex page you linked in fact.

Comment: @SimonPollard Sure, I did enter these values for the used images.

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim where did you enter those values?

Comment: @PeterM as I mentioned, print_r($img_meta) gave empty values for caption and title even used images have these values entered.

Comment: @SimonPollard In Wordpress media library.

Comment: [focal_length] => 0 [iso] => 0 is something I can not even change but caption and title can be entered or modified within wordpress media library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The caption and title you are looking to get from wp_get_attachment_metadata are not the title and caption you add in WordPress they are meta data from the actual image itself. To get the WordPress data use something like this (assuming $id is the id of your image).

```
$image = get_post($id);
$image_title = $image->post_title;
$image_caption = $image->post_excerpt;
```

Comment: Could you share reference page on that?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-title-alt-or-caption-from-media-library-and-insert-into-theme for the exact code - the main thing is that wp_get_attachment_metadata is not getting what you need, though I can see why you would use it, the name is very confusing :)

Comment: That solution did not gave the requested values

Comment: I have updated my answer with new code - and tested. This should work.

Comment: Glad to hear it @IhabAbdel-Rahim :)

Comment: Works nicely on Wordpress 4.8.1

Answer (score 8):

Since WordPress 4.6.0 there is [`get_the_post_thumbnail_caption($post)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_caption/) which gets you the caption for the specified post.

Comment: You can pass it the $post though to get the specific value

Answer (score 0):

put this in your functions.php file:

```
function show_caption_image($type='title'){
  global $post;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,'post_status' => null, 'numberposts' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
      $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
      $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
      $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
      $description = $image->post_content;
    }
  }  
  return $type == 'title' ? $image_title : $caption.$description;
}
```

and below the image in your theme, or wherever you prefer to put it, usually in the single.php file:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
        ?>
      <span class="image main"><img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url()?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title()?>" /><i><?php echo show_caption_image();?></i></span>
      <?php endif; ?>
```