# How to show caption in Gallery images in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

hi I have portfolio blog and under portfolio page, I show my images as image feed and add via gallery its show simply no hyperlink no title no caption

I want to show the only caption on every image

here is code use to display image in my theme

```
    <?php 
    global $post;
    $header_images = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ebor_gallery_images', 1); 

    if( is_array($header_images) ) :
?>

<ul class="basic-gallery text-center">
    <?php 
        foreach( $header_images as $id => $content ){
            echo '<li>'. wp_get_attachment_image($id, 'large') .'</li> ';

        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

how add caption in this help me out for this

thanks !

Comment: please add a var_dump of $header_images, there I guess you would see the required attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress get attachment image caption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658739/wordpress-get-attachment-image-caption)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658739/wordpress-get-attachment-image-caption my answer there is valid here

Comment: nope thats not show caption check i added $header_image code too @niklas

Comment: those link niot helpfull already try @Simon Pollard

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach`:

```
$attachment_title = get_the_title($id)
```

should get you the title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<ul class="basic-gallery text-center">
    <?php 
        $output = '';
        foreach( $header_images as $id => $content ){
            $output .= '<li>'. wp_get_attachment_image($id, 'large');
            $image = get_post($id);
            $output .= '<span class="caption>'.$image->post_excerpt.'</span>';
            $output .= .'</li> ';
        }
        echo $output;
        $output = '';
    ?>
</ul>
```

Output your caption in whatever container you want, I just used a span as an example.

Comment: FYI the except for the image is the caption

Comment: but here those caption come which we add through gallery option so for every image different caption so what i use in output @Simon Pollard

Comment: the_excerpt(); this work for excerpt and show what for caption @Simon Pollard

Comment: The excerpt and the caption are the same thing for images - unless your image gallery works in a different way

Comment: nope its portfolio in this excerpt is for post content and we add images in this so in every image need to add caption that's the point not able to add caption ,see finch WordPress theme for demo hope you understand my point @Simon Pollard

Comment: Do the images you add appear in the media library (click on media in the left of admin) ?

Comment: yh i add those images from media gallery @Simon Pollard

Comment: The captions are added to those images - if you edit an image from the media library you can add a caption. The code I gave should display that caption.

Comment: the_excerpt(); define for portfolio post content so when i use this its show page content instead of caption in database caption store in post_excerpt and image description store in post_content dont knw from where its take post data @Simon Pollard

Comment: Have you even tried my code? it is not using the_except() when you use my code what gets output in the span?

Comment: page get only load nothing display spinner not stop when use your code @Simon Pollard

Comment: .$image->post_excerpt. your code not give any output

Comment: Ok then your images do not have an caption. Go into the media manager find an image and add a caption to it, save and then re-load. If that does not work I am not sure where else to go without looking at your whole site I am afraid.

Comment: make any post and add caption in image show in post but not show in portfolio page !

Comment: If you var_dump($image); in the loop after  $image = get_post($id); does that return information about the image - or about the page its on?

Comment: 'captions'  => ! apply_filters( 'disable_captions', '' ), this i found in wp-includes/media.php what is this @Simon Pollard

Comment: and using var_dump($image); giving null output @Simon Pollard

Comment: Not sure about the function in media.php but that is a core WordPress file so do not alter that. If $image is giving null then I am very confused, the image is displaying above fine?